# How can I speed up Matlab matrix multiplication that is running very slowly on a VM on a Server?

Tags: matlab, performance, virtual-machine, windows-server

I used matlab bench to bench matlab on a Laptop and on a Server:( VM ).
I also did matrix multiplication that shows a drastic difference.

But the bench of the server shows it to be better than the laptop.
Guessing the Windows:VM to be a problem.  Not sure how to improve speed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is "buy a better computer" a useful answer? I don't know if you can get any other answer than that...

Comment: I guess there are other VMs on the server also using the processor?

Comment: Your server CPU is 5 years older than your laptop CPU. Add the virtualization overhead, with whatever else is running on the machine, and a factor 2 slower is not at al weird.

Comment: What Cris said. Also, the server Xeon chips are on a slower cadence than home Core chips; their single-core performance typically lags behind by a couple years. So it's more like you're running a 7-year-old CPU on that server.

Comment: But the big question is: how many cores/vCPUs do you actually have allocated to that server? The reference benchmark you posted is probably done using all cores of the Xeon in a non-virtualized environment. The E5-2650L has 8 cores. How many of them are you using in your VM? If your VM only has 4 GB of RAM, I'm guessing you only have 1 or 2 vCPU cores on that instance.

Comment: "the server is supposed to be better than the server" – do you mean "the server is supposed to be better than the laptop"?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a problem with Matlab or Windows. You probably just have a slow VM. That Xeon E5-2650L is [eight years old now (launched in early 2012](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html)), and it doesn't look like you have many cores/vCPUs allocated to your VM.

That reference benchmark you posted is probably using all eight cores of the E5-2650L they're testing. I'm guessing that since you've only got 4 GB of RAM in your VM instance, you only have one or two vCPU cores allocated. So you're not getting nearly the performance that the benchmark indicates.

If you want your Matlab code to go faster, just upgrade your VM. Sorry there's no free fix here.